# Android Studio Layout Builder Exception

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, exception, android-studio-2.3

My android studio is currently not loading the content of my layout files. The editor is showing me the following exception:

```
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: ViewBackgroundHelper
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatBackgroundHelper.loadFromAttributes(AppCompatBackgroundHelper.java:46)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:73)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:66)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.createNewInstance(ViewLoader.java:475)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadClass(ViewLoader.java:262)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadClass(ViewLoader.java:213)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.LayoutlibCallbackImpl.loadClass(LayoutlibCallbackImpl.java:193)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:333)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.onCreateView(BridgeInflater.java:152)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:717)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:785)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:222)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:858)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:70)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:834)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.bars.CustomBar.<init>(CustomBar.java:95)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.bars.NavigationBar.<init>(NavigationBar.java:52)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.bars.NavigationBar.<init>(NavigationBar.java:46)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.Layout.createNavBar(Layout.java:284)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.Layout.<init>(Layout.java:140)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:301)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:429)
    at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:368)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:567)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:549)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:863)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:549)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$inflate$1(RenderTask.java:680)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Does anyone have an idea why this error appear and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for my problem. Gradle somehow assigned the latest support lib to my project (26 beta2), which it should only do if I use the flavor "devAndroidO". I have reported that issue to google.